# How to create an array of sub objects of varying size

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to create an array of sub objects DubPrime of varying size within the class Cluster P. However, it doesn't let me create an array the size of dubPrimeCount, presumably because you can't create an array with an uninitialized size?

I want to have it so that the user defines the amount of DubPrimes that is encapsulated in ClusterP.

Are there any workarounds for this?

```
    class ClusterP{
    private: 
        int dubPrimeCount;
        DubPrime* dArr[dubPrimeCount];
    public:
        ClusterP(){
            int dubPrimeCount = 5;
            for(int i = 0; i < dubPrimeCount; i++){
                dArr[i] = new DubPrime();
            }
        }
    
};
```

Comment: `std::vector` is the container you wanted.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I was told not to use vectors or other containers for my assignment ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new []` and `delete []` to manage your dynamic array. You may rerence the document [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

```
#include <vector>
class DubPrime {};
class ClusterP {
 private:
  int dubPrimeCount;
  DubPrime *dArr;

 public:
  ClusterP() : dubPrimeCount(5), dArr(new DubPrime[dubPrimeCount]) {}
  ~ClusterP() { delete[] dArr; }
};
```

Or use `std::unique_ptr` to embrace the RAII idiom (with c++14 you can use `std::make_unique`):

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class DubPrime {};
class ClusterP3 {
 private:
  int dubPrimeCount;
  std::unique_ptr<DubPrime[]> dArr;

 public:
  ClusterP3() : dubPrimeCount(5), dArr(new DubPrime[dubPrimeCount]) {}
};
```

If you can use STL, then you may choose to use `std::vector`, it's handy and safer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it would probably be easiest to use an `std::vector<DubPrime *>` instead of an array.

But I believe you could also do:

```
DubPrime **dArr;
```

Then in the constructor,

```
dArr = new (DubPrime*)[dubPrimeCount]
```

and somewhere later, probably in a destructor

```
delete[] dArr;
```

Comment: I believe the questioner meant that the *array* should be of varying size (and not that the objects in the array should be of different sizes).  If so, then a `std::vector<DubPrime>` should suffice, as would `DubPrime * dArr = new DubPrime[dubPrimeCount];`